# Parse Results of Google Elevation Using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, google-maps-api-3, elevation

I'm new to JSON and parsing.  I get the following results when requesting an elevation from the Google Elevation API.

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "location": {
      "lat": 39.7391536,
      "lng": -104.9847034
    },
    "elevation": 1608.8402100
  } ]
}
```

When parsing, I don't know how to effectively reference the elevation using the json_decode results. My abridged code is below:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$geoElevation = $parsed_json->{'elevation'};
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't access the "elevation" value using the above?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

echo $parsed_json->results[0]->elevation;
```

or if you prefer using array:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);

echo $parsed_json['results'][0]['elevation'];
```

The second argument:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
>   from the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) manual

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`print_r($parsed_json)`](http://php.net/print_r) to get a better visualization of your data structure:

```
$parsed_json
(
    [status] => OK
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 39.739153600000001631542545510456
                            [lng] => -104.98470340000000078362063504755
                        )    
                    [elevation] => 1608.8402100000000700674718245864
                )
        )
)
```

This is an array, which you get by using [`json_decode($json_string, TRUE);`](http://php.net/json_decode). That makes it easier to traverse the entries.

In your case you want:

```
 print $parsed_json["results"][0]["elevation"];
```

Normally you would want to `foreach` over the numeric levels. But if you only expect one result, then `[0]` is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So I am referencing it incorrectly. I must parse it as an Array rather than the other method I was using?

Comment: No, you don't have to do it. But it often makes it easier. -- See BOZs answer for the according syntax. The structure remains the same.